# Add AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder in Translation

Tags: c#, ssas

I have a Dimension Attribute called `Location.City` and I my cube supports 3 languages. English by default, and any other 2 languages. Adding the translation objects to the Translations collection is easy, but what I am having the most difficult is adding the translation for the other 2 languages for `AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder`. The only thing I can do right now is add the `AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder` to the `DimensionAttribute` object, but that doesn't help because it is only 1 language. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I'm using C#, .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because in order to set the `AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder` on an Attribute, you on need to set it on `DisplayFolder`. For some reason, they point to the same value.